# How can an include path be updated based on the calling file in a php class

Tags: php, oop, require-once

I've got a bunch of add-ons that I've created that use the same root files, with different configuration files (each add-on is different enough to merit this), and I want to reuse the classes from a "common" directory.

The problem stems from those different configuration files.
Each common script needs to include the correct configuration file.  How can I do something like so:

```
require_once $filepath/config.inc
class someclass  {
...
```

Where the link/button clicked on sends the correct filepath?

Comment: Have you checked documentation for `require_once`? It's pretty straightforward in describing that the path of the required file is a string. So you can construct it as you'd construct any other string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__`, which returns the diretory of the current file. Something like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/path/to/file.inc';
```